# Char Parsing newline (C#)

Tags: c#, split, newline, string-parsing

the problem is simple but I can't figure out a way to overcome this.My applciation recieve a string (stringID) which is a list of IDs, either separated ";"+new line or just newline like :

```
ID1;
ID2;
ID3;
```

or

```
ID1
ID2
ID3
```

What im trying is to get a table with all those IDs ;

I tried :

```
string[] tabID = stringID.Split(';', char.Parse(Environment.NewLine));
```

And

```
string[] tabID = stringID.Split(';', '\r\n')); 
string[] tabID = stringID.Split(';','\n');
```

nothing worked, can anyone help me ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the class StringReader and its method ReadLine to read each line individually.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than using `.Split()`.

Answer (score 2):

The newline property is a string that can be one or two characters long, so use strings when you split. Use the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option, otherwise you will get the empty strings that are between the semicolon and the newlines.

```
string[] tabID = stringID.Split(
  new string[] { ";", Environment.NewLine },
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {';','\n'});
```

There is an overload for [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) which takes a `char[]` of many separators.

Comment: @Reniuz what do you mean? The OP has not used an overload that exists, there is none that takes a `params char[]`

Comment: this `string[] tabID = stringID.Split(';','\n');` from question same as in your answer

Comment: sorry -1. But I have something new for you :) [take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String test = "ID1;ID2;ID3;";
String[] testarr = test.Split(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] tabID = stringID.Split(new Char[] { ';', '\n', '\r'},
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```